# How do i check switch button is on or off in selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to validate/check the state of a button switch element and if it different from the inputed argument it will click the button: [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qOPk.png)

```
<button id="form-user_status" type="button" role="switch" aria-checked="true" class="ant-switch ant-switch-checked" xpath="1">
```

But it seem i cant get it right. i tried a few method :

1. Check 'aria-checked' attribute value and compare it to inputed string argument

```
public void SetFormStatus(string data)
        {
            if (driver.FindElement(FormStatus).GetAttribute("aria-checked") != data)
            {
                driver.FindElement(FormStatus).Click();
            }
        }
```

but the problem is aria-checked value is changing from *`true/false`* when in creating new form item to *`0/1`* when viewing detail item.

2. Using `driver.FindElement(FormStatus).Selected` and compare it to inputed bool argument but `.Selected` return wrong, even when button active it return false.

For now i used brute method to work around it :

```
public void SetFormStatus(bool data)
        {
            bool currentStatus;
            if (driver.FindElement(FormStatus).GetAttribute("aria-checked") == "true" || driver.FindElement(FormStatus).GetAttribute("aria-checked") == "1")
            {
                currentStatus = true;
            }
            else
            {
                currentStatus = false;
            }

            if (currentStatus != data)
            {
                driver.FindElement(FormStatus).Click();
            }
        }
```

It work for now but is there other legit way to check this kinda button? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, coming from my JavaScript/CSS background.

You Need To check based on the class of the `element`(element = your switch button).

Generally UI Frameworks like **`Bootstrap`**,(The one you are using I believe).
when its checked it adds the class `ant-switch-checked` at the class attribute.

so I recommend that you check if the button has the class `ant-switch-checked`
then it'll be 100% clicked.